# 特定の期間ごとに集計する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, sql, rails-activerecord

現在RailsとMySQLを利用したwebアプリケーションでレコードを集計しております。

ActiveRecordでは、groupを用いる事で上手く日毎、週間、月間のレコードを集められているのですが、特定の期間毎に集計する方法に悩んでいます。

例えば

```
User.group("WEEK(created_at)").count
User.group("MONTH(created_at)").count
User.group("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d')").count
```

です。

これらはhashになって日付と個数でかえってくるので非常に利便性が高いのですが、
一方で例えば3日毎に、2週間毎に、3ヶ月毎に集計する等の特定期間での集計が分からず困っています。どなたか教えて頂けますと幸いです....

Googleのこちら([Google LineChart](http://qiita.com/succi0303/items/745fddfc3689a867759c))を用いて出力もするので、可能であれば前述の３つのようにhashでかえってくるととてもありがたいです。

どなたかお願いします！

Comment: Qiitaに書いた方がいいんでしょうか？

Comment: 優しいかたが編集してくださったようですね

Comment: 解答欲しいなあ〜〜〜どなたか〜〜〜〜〜

Comment: 質問内容に関わらないようなコメントは控えたほうが良いと思いますよ。あなたの質問専用に２４時間誰かがスタンバイしているわけではありません。

Comment: すいません。
でも昔英語版で質問したら比較的早く返事がきたので。
anyway助かりました。

Comment: 英語版の方がユーザベースが多いので、日本語版オンリーの当サイトよりは早く何らかの回答が得られる率は高いようですね。日本語版の場合、「この方は週一くらいでしかアクセスできないのかな」と思われる方が素晴らしい回答をつけられている場合も多いので、少し長めのスパンで待たれた方が良いと思います。その場合でも、より回答がつけやすくなるようななんらかの情報を付加したり、質問内容そのものの改善を試みるみたいな内容にした方が回答を促す効果があると思いますよ。

Comment: なるほど、次回はそのように致しますね。ご指摘ありがとうございましたー！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この手の集計処理は生SQLでガツンと集計するのが手っ取り早いと思います。
以下は2016年1月で3日おきに集計する例です。

```
sql = <<-SQL
SELECT
c.dt_from,
c.dt_to,
COUNT(u.id) AS cnt
FROM
(SELECT
   @f:='2016-01-01' AS dt_from,
   DATE_ADD(@f, INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS dt_to
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
   @f:=DATE_ADD(@f, INTERVAL 3 DAY) AS dt_from,
   DATE_ADD(@f, INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS dt_to
 FROM
   users
 WHERE
   @f < '2016-01-31'
) AS c -- cはcalendarのc
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u
ON c.dt_from <= DATE(u.created_at) AND DATE(u.created_at) <= c.dt_to
GROUP BY c.dt_from, c.dt_to
ORDER BY c.dt_from
SQL

users = User.find_by_sql(sql)
users.map(&:attributes)
# => [{"dt_from"=>"2016-01-01", "dt_to"=>"2016-01-03", "cnt"=>3}, {"dt_from"=>"2016-01-04", "dt_to"=>"2016-01-06", "cnt"=>7}, ...]
```

SQLの実行結果はこちらで確認することができます。

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b381c/4

ただし、このSQLはタイムゾーンを特に考慮していないので、環境によっては日本時間におけるx月x日の集計とは多少ずれるかもしれません。

### 追伸

週間、月間の集計ですが、

```
User.group("WEEK(created_at)").count
User.group("MONTH(created_at)").count
```

このままだと他の年もごちゃまぜに集計されてしまうので、年の違いを考慮した方がいいと思います。以下は一例です。

```
User.group("YEARWEEK(created_at)").count
User.group("CONCAT(YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at))").count
```

Comment: なんと追伸までありがとうございます！
またデータ量がそこまでない状態だったので現状は問題がなかったのですが、助かりました！参考にさせて頂きます。

Comment: すいませんこれ完全に追伸の箇所にしか気付いて居ませんでした。
これ無茶苦茶助かりました！
実際にやっぱりサンプルコード書いてくださる方がいると本当に助かりますね。まだsof始めたばかりでupvoteできないのですが、解除され次第絶対しますね！本当に助かりましたm(_ _)m

Comment: お役に立てて良かったです！もし問題が解決したら、こちらを参考にして回答の承認をお願いします。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers 承認してもらうと質問者の信用度もアップしますので。（あとこちらも参考にどうぞ => http://blog.jnito.com/entry/2015/10/04/073825 ）

Answer (score 0):

要はgroup()では、指定されたSQL式の計算結果に応じて分類集計する(例えば`"MONTH(created_at)"`なら「計算結果」は1から12なので、1から12で集計されるわけです)だけで、内部的にはSQLのGROUP BYを使っているので、GROUP BYに指定してうまく動くような式を考えてgroup()の引数に指定してやれば良いということになります。

例えば四半期であれば、MySQL関数にQUARTERというのがありますので、こんな感じにすれば期待の結果が得られると思います。

```
User.group("CONCAT(YEAR(created_at), QUARTER(created_at))").count
```

*3日毎に、2週間毎に、* というのは年をまたいだときにどう分類すれば良いのか細かい仕様がわからないとなんとも言えないのですが、仕様を明確化してストアドファンクションを作ってしまって、そのファンクションを記載するのが手っ取り早いでしょう。

```
User.group("every3days(created_at)").count
```

every3daysは日付を引数に取り3日ごとの代表日(2016-01-01,2016-01-02,2016-01-03に対しては2016-01-01、2016-01-04を含む3日には2016-01-04等々)を返すように作ったストアドファンクションという想定です。

Comment: おお！解答ありがとうございます！
ストアドファンクションというのを知らなかったです。
ActiveRecord側で無理矢理やろうとしていましたがたしかにmysql側で操作した方が良さそうですね。
助かりました。試してみます。

Answer (score 0):

Junichi Itoさんが投稿されてる
ユーザ変数を使う方法ですが

OracleACEのAketiJyuuzouさんとyoku0825さんと
日本オラクルの木村明治さんによると
MySQLのユーザ変数は評価順序が未定義です。
http://qiita.com/AketiJyuuzou/items/cced9b70cc714b382d98

なので、結果が保証されません。